# changing from old style to new style joins with separate tables

Tags: plsql

i have a query in which im using two tables to join two columns, my query is working fine, but when i try to change it to the new style i got stuck in the joins here is my query

```
    SELECT c.*,e.status,
CASE
  WHEN e.status <> 'A' THEN c.usuclaveautorizaapoyo
  ELSE c.usuclaveautoriza
END
FROM    empleados e, configuracion_sensores_emp c, usuarios u, empleados e2, usuarios u2
WHERE   e.empnum = u.empnumnm
AND     u.trabnum = e.trabnum
AND     c.usuclaveautoriza  = u.usuclave
AND     e2.empnum = u2.empnumnm
AND     u2.trabnum = e2.trabnum
AND     c.usuclaveautorizaapoyo = u2.usuclave
```

and here is where im stuck

```
SELECT c.*,e.status,
CASE
  WHEN e.status <> 'A' THEN c.usuclaveautorizaapoyo
  ELSE c.usuclaveautoriza
END
FROM    empleados e
JOIN    usuarios u ON e.empnum = u.empnumnm
AND     u.trabnum = e.trabnum
JOIN    configuracion_sensores_emp c ON c.usuclaveautoriza = u.usuclave
????    empleados e2  <------- how can i be able to join or add this to the code?
JOIN    usuarios u2 ON e2.empnum = u2.empnumnm
AND     u2.trabnum = e2.trabnum 
AND     c.usuclaveautorizaapoyo = u2.usuclave
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*,e.status,
CASE
  WHEN e.status <> 'A' THEN c.usuclaveautorizaapoyo
  ELSE c.usuclaveautoriza
END
FROM    empleados e
JOIN    usuarios u ON e.empnum = u.empnumnm
AND     u.trabnum = e.trabnum
JOIN    configuracion_sensores_emp c ON c.usuclaveautoriza = u.usuclave
JOIN    usuarios u2 ON c.usuclaveautorizaapoyo = u2.usuclave
JOIN    empleados e2  ON e2.empnum = u2.empnumnm
AND     u2.trabnum = e2.trabnum
```